# Get the value of a stored procedure inside another stored procedure with select

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure as you can see

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPViewMTOByLineIdAndTestPackageId] 
    @PackId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT      
        *, 
        ISNULL(dbo.ReturnShortageByItemCodeLinePackage(LineId, TestPackageId, MaterialDescriptionId), 0) AS Shortage,
        ISNULL(dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId, TestPackageId, MaterialDescriptionId), 0) AS totalIMIV,
        ISNULL(dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId, TestPackageId, MaterialDescriptionId), 0) AS TotalMIV,
       ISNULL(dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDesriptionId(LineId, TestPackageId, MaterialDescriptionId), 0) AS TotalMRC,
       ISNULL(dbo.WarehouseByMaterialdesciptionId(MaterialDescriptionId), 0) AS Warehouse
FROM
    dbo.ViewMTO 
WHERE 
    TestPackageId = @PackId
```

As you can see, this stored procedure accepts an input and return some values. I want to call this stored procedure from another stored procedure with `select statement` to get the values like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE secondSP
AS
    declare @a nvarchar(max)
BEGIN
    select @a = shortage 
    from SPViewMTO(1)    // The input value @PackId is 1 for example
END
```

Comment: Procedure cant be used like you have. Use a table valued function instead

Comment: @AksheyBhat can call store procedure in tabular function  ?

Comment: Yoг are altering procedure inside another procedure?? No, you can not use SP inside functions.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar just put your select query inside table valued function

Comment: And what if you got more then 1 different values in `shortage`? You will pass to `@a` only *first one*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a table value function for getting packet info:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SPViewMTOByLineIdAndTestPackageId(@PackId int)
    RETURNS @packInfo TABLE 
    (
        Shortage int , 
        totalIMIV int , 
        TotalMIV int , 
        JobTitle int , 
        TotalMRC int 
    )
    AS 
    -- Returns the first name, last name, job title, and contact type for the specified contact.
    BEGIN
    SELECT      *,isnull(dbo.ReturnShortageByItemCodeLinePackage(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) As Shortage
    ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as totalIMIV
    ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMIV
    ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDesriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMRC
               ,isnull(dbo.WarehouseByMaterialdesciptionId(MaterialDescriptionId),0) As Warehouse

     from 
    dbo.ViewMTO where  TestPackageId=@PackId
    END
```

Modify your second proc as below :

```
   Create PROCEDURE secondSP
    AS
    declare @a nvarchar(max)
    BEGIN

            select @a=shortage from   dbo.SPViewMTOByLineIdAndTestPackageId(1)

    END
```